# A Bash script to upload images to imgur.com automatically asking for new access_token

Tags: bash, oauth-2.0, command-line-interface, image-uploading, imgur

I was wondering if there's an already written **Bash script** which will be capable of uploading images to imgur.com along **with automating the process of requesting new access token** once it expire.

Searching for such a script I found a few which do not support OAuth2:

Quoted from Imgur's OAuth2.0 overview

> The Imgur API uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication. OAuth 2.0 has four steps: registration, authorization, making the request, and **getting new *access_tokens* after the initial one expired**.

Searching in [Imgur's uploading tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT3CW.jpg) I found scripts that do not support OAuth2.0, therefore they are not relevant for my case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote such a tool a few days ago: [rugmi](https://github.com/RanyAlbegWein/Rugmi).

Here are a few usage examples:

```
Upload foo.png, bar.png, baz.png and print the result links to stdout.
$ rugmi -f foo.png -f bar.png -f baz.png
    or
$ rugmi -- foo.png bar.png baz.png

Upload all JPEG files in a directory and print the result links to stdout.
$ find dir/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | rugmi -0

Upload foo.png and print an HTML type of link to be displayed as a medium thumbnail.
rugmi -f foo.png -t HTML -s MT
```