# Upload image to my account on Imgur (not anonymously)

Tags: javascript, api, upload, imgur

I'm working on an application that will upload images to Imgur, using Javascript.

I would like the image to be uploaded to my Imgur account. I created an application and got my client_id and client_secret. Although, I am not sure how I can upload as me.

When I try to authorize with OAuth2, Imgur redirects me to a login form (which I don't want). I would like to get directly the access token to upload to my account.

Is there any way to do that? If not, is there any alternative service that would do that?

Thanks.

Comment: This post will help you achieve that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377029/a-bash-script-to-upload-images-to-imgur-com-automatically-asking-for-new-access

Comment: Accessing the url `https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize` returns an HTML  login form. Not the pin...

Comment: Guess, you need to try, `https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=pin` replacing the `CLIENT_ID` with yours.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JVLYo.png

Comment: Can you please paste the url in a browser windows instead of postman?

Comment: I tried too. I get the same thing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EPsfV.png